# Какие есть наказания за то что сайт не открывался?

Tags: seo

Последние 5-6 месяцев сайт не работал примерно по 30 минут 5-6 раз.
Последний раз, несколько дней назад, тоже был такой случай. 
Посетителей из Яндекса было по ~2000 в сутки, и после упало до ~400. Количество индексируемых страниц тоже упало, но не так сильно.

- Этот период навсегда?
- Или пройдёт определённое количество времени и всё вернётся на свои места?
- Что можно делать чтобы уладить ситуацию?

Если есть полезные ссылки, где можно прочитать про это - поделитесь пожалуйста.

---

Через неделю сайт восстановил количество посетителей.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 1. Этот период на всегда?

Нет.

> 2. Или пройдёт определённое количество времени и всё вернётся на свои места?

Если не будет перебоев в работе сайта, тогда да.

> 3. Что можно делать чтобы уладить ситуацию?

Мониторинг работы сайта.

Comment: а есть ссылки на какие-то оффициальные источники?

Comment: сейчас не смогу предоставить именно ссылку, но могу объяснить причину просадки трафика, позиции в поиске формируются за счет поведенческого фактора пользователей которые перешли на ваш сайт по определенному запросу, когда ваш сайт недоступен поисковая машина считает что пользователь не смог получить от вашего сайта качественный контент, так как он не получил к нему доступ, соответственно понижается позиция сайта. если вы мониторите места своего сайта в поиске вы это заметите. Подробнее можно прочитать в яндекс вебмастере, но к сожалению в каком разделе не помню.

Comment: было бы здорово если вспомнили бы раздел вебмастера, заранее спасибо за Ваш ответ!

Comment: https://yandex.ru/support/webmaster/diagnosis/fatal.html#diagnostics-fatal__dns-error

Comment: тут мало, но недоступный сайт считается фатальной ошибкой

Comment: фатальная ошибка, это что значит? что свои посетители из Яндекса сайт уже не вернёт?

Comment: Совсем нет. Это совет яндекса по ошибкам, если вы исправите ситуацию, через некоторое время все вернется.
Совет. Отслеживайте и исправляйте ошибки в кратчайшие сроки. Вы можете настроить уведомления о результатах проверки сайта.

Comment: отлично, тогда сразу исправили проблему, спасибо ещё раз